# Find value within object - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with trying to see if a value matches within an array that contains one objects.

Here is what I am doing:

```
var found = $.inArray(opt.ifpo_width, selectedOptions) > -1;
```

Lets say `opt.ifpo.width` contains `650`.  `selectedOptions` contains an object with a value of `650` so I will want `found` to return 0 because it that means the value has been found.

Heres an example of `console.log` of `selectedOptions`:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
active: true
......
ifpo_width: "650" <-- value I am checking
ifpo_x: "153"
ifpo_y: "86"
shown: false
__proto__: Object
1: Object
active: true
ifpo_width: "650" <-- this other object should not be here because there is already a width of the same value.
ifpo_x: "140"
ifpo_y: "102"
.....
```

What are your suggestions and thoughts about how I can check this `selectedOptions` for the value being checked with `opt.ifpo_width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ifpo_width can change, you can use a function like that

```
    function search(property, arr, value) {
        var t;
        for (t = 0; t < arr.length; t++) {
            if (arr[t][property] == value)
                return true;
        }

        return  false;
    }
```

and call it with

```
search("ifpo_width", YourArray, selectedOptions)
```

otherwise, more simple

```
    function search(arr, value) {
        var t;
        for (t = 0; t < arr.length; t++) {
            if (arr[t].ifpo_width == value)
                return true;
        }

        return  false;
    }
```